# how to take an apk using cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-camera

By Using Cordova, Needed sdk version is 33. Using cordova, With angular DIST.The angular version is 6.need Camera,file accessing. write down in steps: Need the version of Cordova,and the requirements.and the steps to perform that.

Answer (score 0):

Steps run the follwing"

```
npm install -g cordova@9.0.0

cordova create myApp com.example.myapp MyApp

cd myApp

cordova platform add android@9.0.0


cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

Update AndroidManifest.xml:

cordova build android

cordova run android
```

After running the above command, Cordova will generate a debug APK. You can find the APK in the following directory:

myApp/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Generate a Release APK:
If you want to generate a release APK for publishing on the Google Play Store:

a. Create a keystore file (if you haven't already):

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

b. Place the my-release-key.keystore file in the root of your Cordova project.

c. Build the release APK:

```
cordova build android --release -- --keystore=my-release-key.keystore --storePassword=your_keystore_password --alias=alias_name --password=your_key_password
```

After running the above command, Cordova will generate a release APK. You can find the APK in the following directory:

```
myApp/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk
```

Install APK on Device:
If you want to install the APK on a device for testing:

```
cordova run android
```